# Android - Obtaining view for Activity title and attaching click listener

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying something crazy here. I would like to attach a click listener to the title of my activity. For this I either need the title view's id or the view itself. Just to keep in mind, I am not defining a custom view for the title. All I do is set the title in the manifest for the appropriate Activity. I would now like to attach a click listener to the title.

How can this be achieved? Some direction or even a solution would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this on `onCreate` of your activity

```
final int abTitleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
findViewById(abTitleId).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Do something
    }
});
```